# Android search through an string-array and get results into a ListView

Tags: android, arrays, string, listview, search

I want to search into a string-array and get the result into a ListView.

So, if I have

```
<string-array name="Colors">
    <item>Red</item>
    <item>Yellow</item>
    <item>Blue</item>
    <item>DarkRed</item>
</string>
```

and I search for "Red", I should get into the ListView two items. For each item I would like to know the ID into the string array and the string value, which would be displayed in the ListView.

While searching for results I would like to display a ProgressBar (indeterminate status) that disappears when all is finished.

A first step would be getting the string-array into a List or String[], then create a new Thread that compares each item of the array and put on the ListView those matching the search text.

I don't know which is the best way of doing it. My code is something like this:

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {
    private ProgressBar mProgress;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);

        mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.Progress);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            int item_pos = 0;
            int item_count = 0;

            String[] Colors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Colors); 
                item_count = Colors.length();

                mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                while (item_pos < item_count) {
                    // Compare with the search text
                    // Add it to the ListView (I don't know how)
                    item_pos +=1;
                }
                mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

So, my questions:

1. How do I get both item id and string then compare each text value with the search text?
2. How do I add an item to the ListView?
3. Why the ProgressBar is not visible? The ProgressBar XML code is this:

   ```
   <ProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/Progress"
       style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:indeterminate="true"
       android:visibility="visible" />
   ```

Thanks for all of your suggestions and help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I'd approach this problem.

First, I'd get my `string-array` like this :

```
    Resources res = getResources();
    String[] colors = res.getStringArray(R.array.Colors);
    // transform into ArrayList for ease of use
    ArrayList<String> colorsList = Arrays.asList(colors);
```

Search for the desired sequence in the list and remove any unwanted elements :

```
for (String s : colorsList) {  
   if (!s.contains("red")) { // hardcoded, only to illustrate my logic
      colorsList.remove(s);
   }
}
```

Now that you have a list free of unwanted elements, simply bind it to your `ListView`, for that I'd recommend an [`ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html). The documentation contains a great article regarding [basic ListView usage](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html).

If your `Activity` is only going to contain a ListView as it's sole element, you could extends your Activity from [`ListActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) instead of `Activity`. It will grant you a couple new benefits like simply calling [`getListView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#getListView%28%29) in order to obtain your ListView easily.

As far as your ProgressBar goes, I'd suggest you look into the [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class, it will provide a more elegant way of dealing with Threading in your application. The Android Dev Team does recommend you use the AsyncTask over the classic `Runnable` approach you're using now.

Lastly, if you're looking for some more code snippets regarding ListViews in general, you should really take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/index.html), it's filled with example from the Android team. It was really helpful to me when I started Android and couldn't get my head around ListViews.

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will do this inside an Async class, I suppose I will get double advantage from it. Thanks again for your time!